# C++ equivalent to the python code: "for x in iterable:"

Tags: c++

I want to do in c++ something like in python would be:

```
nums=[31, 46, 11, 6, 14, 26]
nlttf=[]
for n in nums:
    if n<25:nlttf.append(n)
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
SomethingIteratable cont;

for (const auto &v : cont) {
    // Do something
}
```

As usual, `const auto &v` gives you immutable references, `auto &v` mutable references and `auto v` mutable deep copies.

Beware: You may not do anything in the loop that invalidates iterators of the container you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have C++11 or greater, then you can do it this way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num[] = {31, 46, 11, 6, 14, 26};
    vector<int>nlttf;
    for(int n:num){
        if(n<25)nlttf.push_back(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203382.aspx) Range-based for Statement (C++).

For **`std::vector`** see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_stl_tutorial.htm) link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11 then the code is the following:

```
for (int n: iterator) { /*Do stuff with n*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using C++11 and the boost libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <vector>
int main(){
  std::vector<int> nums {31, 46, 11, 6, 14, 26};
  std::vector<int> nltff;
  BOOST_FOREACH(auto n, nums) if (n < 25) nltff.push_back(n);
  BOOST_FOREACH(auto n, nltff) std::cout << n << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
11 6 14
```